# Calculate inflection points with R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a "variance filtering using the inflexion point of ranked list of median absolute deviation values" to reproduce a paper.

So far I obtained the median absolute values (MAD :) with `mad`:

```
mad.v <- apply(x, 2, mad, na.rm = T)
mad.v <- mad[!is.na(mad.v)]
```

Then I create a function to calculate the percentage of those values

```
count.p <- function(data, per){
  # Calculates the percentatge above some data
  sum(data >= per)/length(data)
}
perc <- unlist(lapply(mad.v, count.p, data = mad.v))
```

When I plot it I obtain something like:

[image: percentatge over values]
Where the vertical blue line is the inflexion point of the blue tendency and the red one for the other. Which I don't really trust, as the red tendency has already changed of concavity before that point.

**How can I obtain the inflection point?**

I have seen the inflection package but I didn't know how to use `ede` properly in the image above that where supposed to be the inflection points. I also found the RootsExtremaInflections package but I neither knew how to use it properlly (I did: `inflexi(mad.v, perc, 3000, 13000, 2, 5, "x", "y", 3,3)`)

Other things I tried are this other [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/76959/105234) and doing myself the [secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method) on the derivatives of the function (which I am unsure how to calculate them)

```
sampledata <- matrix(rnbinom(5000, 2, 0.5), 10, 500)
```

Comment: Yes, it is really a nature letter: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v523/n7562/full/nature14468.html

Comment: Thanks. In the full text version of the article do they show any code? Did they use R? Jw.

Comment: They use R for sure, they mention several packages of Bioconductor an CRAN. They don't show any code

Comment: OK great which packages?

Comment: hopach, WGCNA, MLInterfaces, GEOquery, vsn are explicitly mentioned